# How do I run `dir` in Dart?

Tags: dart

How can I run the `dir` command from the Dart VM? When I try to use it with the `Process` class I get "unhandled exceptions".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Søren Gjesse for the answer, who originally [posted this to the Dart mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/misc/x7CRDeo1-os).

You cannot just run `dir` on Windows as it is not a standalone executable but build into `cmd.exe`. The following code will run `dir` and print the result:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
    Process.run('cmd', ['/c', 'dir']).then((ProcessResult results) {
      print(results.stdout);
    });
}
```

See also the [Dart IO library](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io.html) for more on processes.